# Trying to leave a trail of particle effects with a Particle system attached to an Object Unity C#

Tags: unity, c#, particles

I have a particle system attached to my game object, which starts to emit particles when I press down the "W" key and stops when I release it. The particle system works fine, but when I rotate the object, the particles rotate with the object. I would like to have the particles leave behind a trail of the path of the object.

Script below:

```
public class Motor : MonoBehaviour {

public ParticleSystem EngineLeft;
public ParticleSystem EngineRight; 


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * Speed);
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.W)) {
        EngineRight.Play ();
        EngineLeft.Play ();
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.W)) {
        EngineRight.Stop ();
        EngineLeft.Stop ();
    }
```

Comment: In this case it would be more important to post the settings of the particle system and a screenshot of the problem instead of your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the "Simulation Space" setting of the particle system from "Local" to "World". That way the position and rotation of the particle system (or its parents) will only affect newly spawned particles and not those already spawned.

Comment: Thanks. This is my first time working with Unity since a few months now and I did not remember this thing.

Comment: I came across a case when "Simulation Space" is set to World, but still the emitted particles follow the rotation of the emitting object. The culprit was "Prewarm" flag. After I disabled it, the particles started moving in world space.